# Phusion Passenger: Getting 404 on all my applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, http-status-code-404, passenger

I hadn't used my MacBook for a while to run some local Rails apps, but now they are all showing (apache) 404s. I believe I had updated to Lion and the newest [Pref Pane](http://electronicholas.com/2011/08/passenger-prefpane-1-5-for-mac-os-x-lion-10-7/) since they last worked. I'm not sure where to start looking to debug. Any ideas?

I also did the following:

```
$ rvm use @global
$ gem update passenger
$ passenger-install-apache2-module
```

My /etc/apache2/httpd.conf contains the following at the end:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /Users/robs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /Users/robs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby /Users/robs/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/ruby

# Added by the Passenger preference pane
# Make sure to include the Passenger configuration (the LoadModule,
# PassengerRoot, and PassengerRuby directives) before this section.
<IfModule passenger_module>
  NameVirtualHost *:80
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName _default_
  </VirtualHost>
  Include /private/etc/apache2/passenger_pane_vhosts/*.conf
</IfModule>
```

PS. They work fine if I run `$ rails s` and go to http://localhost:3000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Restart Apache and recheck :)
2. Ensure there's not some master on/off switch in the Pref Pane that is off
3. kill the pref pane and these sections of your apache config and just set up a vhost manually [as described here](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_macos_x). Recheck
4. Switch to [pow](http://pow.cx)

Comment: No luck with the other steps, but Pow looks really great. Thanks. Followup question: How do you run it in production mode using Pow?

Comment: sure, set the RAILS_ENV to production using [the method noted here](http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.2)

Comment: Great! I included `export RAILS_ENV=production` in .powenv in my app root. Thanks for your help, @austinfromboston.